# fillna rows based on previous and next row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this kind of df :

```
values
str1
str1
nan
nan
str1
nan
nan
str2
nan
nan
str2
```

`values` are `str`. I want to fillna where rows are surrounded by the same value and get :

```
values
str1
str1
str1
str1
str1
nan
nan
str2
str2
str2
str2
```

Is there an option in the `fillna` function that can do that ?

EDIT :

Is there also an option to set a limit of number of rows between two str_i to fill ?

Comment: have you tried `df["values"].fillna(method="ffill", limit=N)`?

Comment: yes but i will replace `nan` between `str1` and `str2` by `str1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way using `ffill` and `bfill`:

```
df2 = df.ffill()
print(df2[df2 == df.bfill()])
```

Output:

```
   values
0    str1
1    str1
2    str1
3    str1
4    str1
5     NaN
6     NaN
7    str2
8    str2
9    str2
10   str2
```